# List<int> in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I am unable to understand the logic behind `List<int>` as it breaks some of the basic rules.

`List<int>` is supposed to be of value type and not reference type.

1. `List<int>` has to be passed by `ref` keyword if its value has to be persisted between function calls. So this means it is displaying a value type behavior similar to int.
2. But `List<int>` has to be initialized by a new operator. Also `List<int>` could be null as well. This implies a reference type behavior.

A nullable type is different as in it does not have to be initialized by new operator.

Am I seeing something wrong here?

EDITED-

I should have posted the code in the original question itself. But it follows here -

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListTest d = new ListTest();
            d.Test();
        }
    }

    class ListTest
    {
        public void  ModifyIt(List<int> l)
        {
            l = returnList();
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            List<int> listIsARefType = new List<int>();
            ModifyIt(listIsARefType);
            Console.WriteLine(listIsARefType.Count); // should have been 1 but is 0
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public List<int> returnList()
        {
            List<int> t = new List<int>();
            t.Add(1);
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with your point 1? Could you give an example why you think that you need `ref`?

Comment: @0xA3 => create a method1 which takes List<int> as its parameter. Then in the main method pass method1 a List<int>. In method1 add some integers to the list. In the main method see if you get those integers back.

Comment: mattmc3 already posted an example like that demonstrating that you don't need `ref`.

Comment: Regarding your code, the problem is that *you are assigning a new list*. Outside code doesn't see the new list - but if you modified the original list instead, it would see those changes.

Comment: @Anon => What do you mean by Outside code does not see the new list ?. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @Prashant: Suppose you have a house, and a postcard that tells you the address of the house. You copy that postcard, and give the copy to someone. If they go to the house and change it, everyone else will see the changed house, but if they build a new house and scribble its address on their postcard, it won't affect anyone else.

Comment: @Prashant - I think what @Anon is trying to describe is that variables holding reference types just hold a reference to a location in memory on the heap. So, 'l' in the 'ModifyIt' method starts off pointing to the same location as 'listIsARefType' but then gets its address changed by the call to 'new List<int>()' and the element gets added to that list...'listIsARefType' is still pointing to original location - which is still an empty list.  Nice question - took me a while to get it! ;-)

Comment: List<int> is not a value type.

Answer (score 30):

> List is supposed to be of value type and not reference type.

*Wrong!*  `int` is a value type.  `List<int>` is a reference type.

Comment: If that were the case why pass by ref the List<int> between functions ?

Comment: @Prash You would do that if you wanted to change the reference itself (ie: set it to null or a different list).  But I wouldn't normally build code to make that necessary.

Comment: @Prashant: you don't need to.  Whoever told you that you do, always, is a moron.  What the `ref` keyword does, is allow you to set the parameter to a whole other `List<int>`.  Which isn't even nearly as common as you seem to think it is.

Comment: Poor, old `ref`; so misunderstood. :)

Answer (score 7):

I think you have a faulty assumption in your first bullet.  The generic List object is definitely a reference type (on the heap, not the stack).  Not sure why you think you have to pass via `ref`.  This prints "2" like it should:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
   class Program {
      static void Main(string[] args) {
         List<int> listIsARefType = new List<int>();
         ModifyIt(listIsARefType);
         ModifyIt(listIsARefType);
         Console.WriteLine(listIsARefType.Count); // 2!
         Console.ReadKey(true);
      }

      static void ModifyIt(List<int> l) {
         l.Add(0);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it's important to notice that any List<T> is a Reference Type due to the fact that it was created from a basetype that is a reference type.

It should be noted that an item that is in the list is potentially not a reference type but it could become a reference type.

Answer (score 6):

You need to understand the difference between *pass by reference*, *pass by value*, and *pass reference by value*.

In the code sample you posted, you're passing the *reference* to the `List<int>` object by *value*. This means that you can mutate the object pointed to by the reference, and the calling code will see these changes. However, the reference itself is passed by value, so if you change the reference to point to a different object altogether, the calling code will not see the changes.

When you use the `ref` keyword, you're passing the reference itself by reference. This means that not only can you change the object that the reference is pointing to, but you can also change the reference itself.

Consider this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int foo = 0;
        DoSomething1(foo);
        Console.WriteLine(foo); // Outputs 0.

        DoSomething1(ref foo);
        Console.WriteLine(foo); // Outputs 1.

        var bar = new List<int>();
        DoSomething2(bar);
        Console.WriteLine(bar.Count); // Outputs 1.

        DoSomething2(ref bar);
        Console.WriteLine(bar.Count); // Outputs 0.
    }

    // Pass by value.
    static void DoSomething1(int number)
    {
        // Can't modify the number!
        number++;
    }

    // Pass by value.
    static void DoSomething1(ref int number)
    {
        // Can modify the number!
        number++;
    }

    // Pass reference by value.
    static void DoSomething2(List<int> list)
    {
        // Can't change the reference, but can mutate the object.
        list.Add(25);
    }

    // Pass reference by reference.
    static void DoSomething2(ref List<int> list)
    {
        // Can change the reference (and mutate the object).
        list = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`List<int>` is indeed a reference type. But the items contained in the list are value types.

Nullable types however are implemented as structs (`struct Nullable<T> where T : struct`) and are therefore value types. The reason that you can simply write

```
int? i = 3;
```

without the `new` keyword is that the above syntax is translated by the compiler automatically into code that will do the following:

```
Nullable<Int32> i = new Nullable<Int32>(3);
```

To get a better understanding of the differences between value type and reference type semantics I would recommend you to read Jon Skeet's article on this topic which will guide you with lots of illustrative code sample:

> **[Jon Skeet: Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)**

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of it as `List<int>` think of it the way that it was written `List<t>`.

List is a **generic class**. It is not a struct.  It is a generic class that can work with value types and reference types.

Answer (score 1):

A `List` is a generic reference type, you are using it with a value type int. But it is still a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the mistaken assumptions dealt with in other answers, you say:

> `List<int>` has to be initialized by a
>   new operator... This implies a
>   reference type behavior.

No, in C# the `new` operator is just the syntax for calling the constructor of a type. It's used for both reference and user-defined value types (`struct`s).

Answer (score 0):

`List<int>` is a reference type.  And it doesn't have to be passed as a reference.

The type of the objects *in* the list is kind-of a value type, except that value-type objects may end up boxed (converted into reference-type objects of a sort) anyway, so..scratch this paragraph once you understand that.

Comment: Note that `List<int>` does *not* require boxing. Only if you place a value type in a `List<object>` boxing will be involved.

Comment: @0xA3: I wasn't sure about how well .net did that.  I know Java's annoying about that, but its Integers are a half-hearted attempt to make primitives look like objects, whereas .net's "primitives" are actual objects.

Answer (score 0):

In ModifyIt() method, when you are writing 'l = returnList()'; 'l' is now pointing to a different location in the memory than that of listIsARefType in your Test() method. Basically by writing 'l' '=' something, you have broken the link between 'l' and 'listIsARefType'. In order to keep the link (that is making sure that both of the objects, 'l' and 'listIsARefType' are pointing to the same location in the memory), you either need to only work on the 'l' object (for example by calling a function on the object), or use the ref keyword in the parameter of the ModifyIt() method.